# Propagator/phase factor of a free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, propagator

I am reading a literature review on modelling standard model particles wavefunctions.
I am struggling with deriving the result Ive attached as a photo:

[image]

[image]

From a quantum mechanics course this year i have learnt that when free particles evolve they acquire a phase factor as a result of propagation, so that part makes sense to me. I tried to derive the original result from the $exp(-iS)$ where $S$ represented the action. For a free particle i wrote classical $L=0.5mx'^2$ for velocity $x'$, and by integrating by parts i found an action of $0.5mx'x\sim 0.5px.$ This is missing the $-Et$ phase factor however so i was wondering if anyone knew where i went wrong?

Comment: Reference? Which page?

Comment: You're using the non-relativistic Lagrangian and the source said to use the relativistic one.

Comment: EPR experiments without “collapse of the wavefunction” ,  B. Keyser, c, L. Stodolsky, page 3/4 of the article

Comment: Does the action have to be calculated differently relativisticly, or can o just integrate the lagrangian with respect to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ConnorBehan noted, the given classical action is relativistic:$$-m\tau=-\frac{mt}{\gamma}=(\beta^2-1)m\gamma t=m\beta\gamma\hat{v}\cdot t\beta\hat{v}-m\gamma t\stackrel{\star}{=}p\cdot x-Et,$$where $\stackrel{\star}{=}$ assumes a constant momentum and $x(0)=0$. I'll leave it to you to consider whether IBP justifies it.

Comment: Im sorry ive given it a few days now and i really can't get the relation between proper time and action, do you have any hints?

Comment: @Adrien The quoted text notes the action is $m\tau$. Are you asking why this is so? Defining $\dot{f}:=\frac{df}{dt}$,$$S=\int mds=\int m\sqrt{dt^2-dx^2}=\int m\sqrt{1-\dot{x}^2}dt=\int\frac{mdt}{\gamma}=\int md\tau.$$

Comment: is ds=root(dt^2-dx^2) a common known result?

Comment: never mind, was being stupid, fully understood now thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what does ds represent here? displacement?